# Writing a large dataframe in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to write a large pandas dataframe (1,00,000+ rows and 23 columns) in a csv file. When i try doing so, i get an error - RecursionError - Maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I have tried multiple suggested options i.e. using chunksize, splitting the list etc but none seems to be working. Can someone please help?

Various options tried as below.

**Option 1:**

```
x_df.to_csv(r"C:\file.csv",index=False, header=False)
```

**Option 2:**

```
MyList = []
MyList =my x_df.values.tolist()
for i in range(0,len(MyList),Chunksize):
    x = []
    x = MyList[i:i+Chunksize]
    with open(r'filename.csv',mode='a',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
       wr = csv.writer(myfile)
       wr.writerows(x)
```

**Option 3:**

```
MyList = []
MyList =my x_df.values.tolist()
filename = (r"C:\file.csv")
import csv
file = open(filename, 'w+', newline = "")
with file:
   write = csv.writer(file)
   write.writerows(MyList)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working with big csv files can be such a pain, I think there are a couple options that might still work for your case.

If you don't absolutely need it to be a csv I think the file saving method [here](https://gist.github.com/ybressler/ba6d0c81e6c6cbc97363b5017ef94017#file-save_massive_excel_file-py) would be a much cleaner option, but it's for xlsx files (found that snippet in a towards data science [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-ridiculously-large-excel-files-in-python-44ba0a7bea24), but I believe that site limits the number of visits you get each month)

The first thought I had to keep it a csv would be pretty similar to chunking, you could output a folder of csv files in small enough chunks that you avoid that error. From there you could recombine the files using the the regular python file writer. I think this would look something like this:

```
MyList = []
MyList =my x_df.values.tolist()
for i in range(0,len(MyList),Chunksize):
    x = []
    x = MyList[i:i+Chunksize]
    with open(f'my_folder/filename{i}-{i+Chunksize}.csv',mode='a',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
       wr = csv.writer(myfile)
       wr.writerows(x)

# Then recombine the files
big_csv = ''
for fname in os.listdir('my_folder'):
    with open(f'my_folder/{fname}') as f:
        # Newline might not be necessary/pay attention to whatever your linedelimiters are
        big_csv += f.read() + '\n'

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    f.write(big_csv)
```

There's probably a better way to do that, but using a string instead of a csv to make it should avoid any memory issues.